# How to get Network device's IP based on device's friendly name

Tags: ruby, vagrant, wsl-2

When I run `ipconfig` on windows I get something like this

```
Wireless LAN adapter Wi-Fi:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::...
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 10....
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.0.0.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 10.128.128.128


Ethernet adapter vEthernet (WSL):

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::...
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 172.30.48.1
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.240.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
```

How can I get the IP of the second device (172.30.48.1 in this case) in ruby? the only clue I have is that its friendly name contains WSL: "vEthernet (**WSL**)"

I tried the following but the windows friendly name is not there.`addr_info.name` is some weird internal name (e.g  ethernet_32778) and not the windows friendly name

```rb
    def get_wsl_ip()
      require 'socket'
      Socket.getifaddrs.each do |addr_info|
        if addr_info.name.include? "WSL"
          puts "WSL IP found: " + addr_info.addr.ip_address
          return addr_info.addr.ip_address
        end
      end
      puts "[WARN] No WSL NIC found. Is WSL running? Won't be able to SSH from WSL"
    end
```

What I'm trying to accomplish is to connect via ssh from WSL2 to a VM that i started in my host using vagrant. the issue i'm having is that vagrant binds the port forwarding for ssh to 127.0.0.1 and I can't connect from WSL so i'm trying to create a new port forwarding rule that binds to the virtual NIC that WSL creates but this IP changes after reboot so I'm trying to add something to my vagrantfile to compute the bind ip dynamically when vagrant is starting the VM

Comment: Just parsing the output of `ipconfig` might be easier?

Comment: i think you're right. i couldn't find a better way